# angularjs reload url not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularjs application. Can anyone explain what is happening or ran into similar problem.

Locally

1. List item
2. start server % ng serve
3. browsing % http://localhost:4200 work
4. within the browser I can click on a link and it navigate there correctly. e.g. http://localhost:4200/contactus
5. When reloading the page with this url http://localhost:4200/contactus, it works.

Prod

1. List item
2. start server % node ./dist/server/bin/www.js
3. browsing % http://host work
4. within the browser I can click on a link and it navigate there correctly. e.g. http://host/contactus
5. When reloading the page with this url http://host/contactus, it does not work.

I read similar questions. Most is referring to URL rewrite but what I'm interested to see is a solution or code sample that work ? Can anyone help

Thanks Heaps

Comment: The app fails to bootstrap as the server doesn't recognize the defined route. In order to fix it you need to re-route this requests to your app url which is `http://localhost:4200 | http://somesite.com`. Another solution `if you can't do this just enable hash # mode, it's what # primarily for: to recognize different routes without server configuration`

Comment: Could you please provide details on step 5, are you getting any error or to what it is redirecting ? any console log errors?

Comment: I updated the post . This is the logs on the browser GET http://host/contactus 500 (Internal Server Error).